# Convey the word 'field' (implying all the participants in a contest or sport)

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, synonymes, sport

> Every March, 68 college basketball teams are invited to compete in the
> NCAA tournament to determine a national champion. First, 8 teams
> participate in 4 “play in” games to reduce the **field** to 64. In the
> first round, 32 games reduce the **field** to 32.

> Chaque année en mars, 68 équipes de basket-ball universitaire sont invitées à participer au tournoi de la NCAA afin de déterminer un champion national. Dans un premier temps, 8 équipes participent à 4 matchs "play in" pour réduire **le nombre de participants** à 64. Au premier tour, 32 matchs réduisent **le nombre de participants** à 32.

Deepl conveys field in this context by 'nombre de participants' but I'm wondering if there is another word or expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

French native here. The correct word, particularly in this case (a large field of competitors), would be the word **plateau**.

Sport journals will often talk about "un plateau relevé" to indicate that the field is very competitive for a given tournament, particularly tennis.

Comment: I'm a french native too, and didn't knew that "plateau" could be used in such a context.
I admit that I don't read sport journals. ;)

Thank you, I learned a new word, today.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific? 'Dans un premier temps, 8 équipes participent à 4 matchs "play in" pour réduire plateau à 64.' would be appropriate?

Comment: "pour réduire le plateau à 64" would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: By the way, how would we say 'play in' to avoid the English?

Comment: Your best choice would be "matchs préliminaires". "Tour préliminaire" (for the play-in round) is commonly used.

Comment: It's worth noting that "playoffs" is already commonly used in French, and "playdown" is getting some popularity, but "play in" would indeed be a bit confusing, even though the context would make it easily understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Someone may provide an alternative word but, as a native french speaker, I absolutely find "nombre de participants" right, here.

Answer (score 1):

« Nombre des qualifiés » est une amélioration de  « nombre des participants ». Je ne vois pas d'autre terme, en particulier aucun terme d'un seul mot.